# onenote level and order properties for pages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

Does the MS-Graph OneNote API support setting level and order properties for pages within a section? It appears that the BETA version allows me to read them, but I need to set them as well

Comment: were you able to find a solution? I've been unable to find documentation that support page index position.  The supported `OneNote REST` operations don't appear to support it.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/how-to/onenote-supported-ops

Comment: For reference: the `pagelevel` property is what allows page order and hierarchy to be *read* (I assume this is what OP is referring to in the beta).